# Sencha Touch View Loading issues

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working with sencha touch application. 
i have done with almost complete application.
but, now my issues is when we navigate through different views of application it takes too much time to load views. i have use navigation controller as a main view.
is there any solution for recover this performance issue ? 
any help will be appreicated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try zipping the sencha touch code with the sencha command tool. It will compress all the code which could load views faster

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/command follow the link to install the sencha command line tool and try to execute the "sencha app build package" command. which shoud point out to the path of your sencha project